# How to use <Link> react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with reactjs and react router.
I have create my router as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>  
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={User} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And in the App component I have a Link to the `"/:id"` path :

```
<Link to={'/'+id} >
```

when I am in the "/" route, my view works fine but now when I click my link, the path changes and my view changes for an instant and then gives an error in the App component (It is the component of the other route) .

I use `"react-router": "^2.8.1".`

> PS: the error is in the setinterval function in the component {App}.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please show your code for your Link and the error you are getting. This is not enough info to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code with `setInterval`?

Comment: @hlfrmn .this is my code setinterval:
setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  =moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');},1000)

Comment: @Chris . this is my code for link:
<Link to={'/'+id} >user</Link>

Comment: @Developper Could you please post a larger chunk of your App component - including the `setinterval` function, the `Link` and preferably the rest of it - it one chunk.

Comment: Please mention the version of React-router that you use too, apart from the code in App.js

Comment: componentDidMount(){
setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  =moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');},1000);
}

And in my return component i have :

<div id="demo" className="demo"></div>

this work in my "/" route but when i click my link , it give an error with this setinterval

Comment: "react-router": "^2.8.1"

Comment: and the error is most probably, `cannot read property innerHTML of undefined`  is it??

Comment: this is my error : TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

is because you are not clearing the interval when you are navigating away from the App component and since it still is running, it tries to access 
`document.getElementId("demo")` which is no longer there

what you need to do is `clear the timer` on `componentWillUnmount`

```
componentDidMount(){ 
        this.interval = setInterval(function(){ 
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
        },1000);
    } 

   componentWillUnmount() {
       clearInterval(this.interval);
   }
```

Comment: Please check this solution and let me know if it works out for you

Comment: yes , the problem is why despite i am in the route of {User} component but th error is in the other component !!

Comment: did you change you componentDidMount function too to store the returned value of setInterval function

Comment: yes , the problem is why despite i am in the route of {User} component but th error is in the other component !!

Comment: Its because of setInterval, since it is not getting cleared when you navigate away

Comment: yes now is works , but the error become with an other setinterval is inside function . please how i can stop it ?

Comment: clear that interval too when the component unmounts, assign the return value of that interval to another class variable like i did for this one in my answer

Comment: my setinterval is in an other function .how i stop it in componentWillUnmount()?

Comment: You just need to clearTimeout giving it an id which is returned by setInterval, you can refer my answer for how to do it for the other one too

Comment: Thank you very much :) . your solution resolved my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use this on the top:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

refer to this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md

Comment: Can i use react-router with 'react-router-dom ?

Comment: react-router-dom is now supported with new versions. Better to use react-router-dom instead of react-router. It might also enhance performance of your app.

Comment: What i should change in the code of create my routes to be work in react-router-dom ?

Comment: Check out this awesome article  https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf.

PS: don't forget to upvote my answer in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Include this at the top `import { IndexRoute} from 'react-router';`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>  
   <IndexRoute path="/" component={App} />
   <Route path="/:id" component={User} />
   </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This will distinguish your main root path with the other path.

Comment: No , dont work and the App component not work , in my "/" route i haven't any view if i add this indexroute.

Comment: @Developper, IndexRoute is not a part of react-router v4 so this won't work if you are using the same verison

Comment: I use "react-router": "^2.8.1"

Comment: Kindly update your question, with the version of the react-router you are using so that people can help you out accordingly. :)